# What do to after hierarchical clustering and finding number of clusters

Tags: multivariate-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, correspondence-analysis

I have a dataset with 10 categorical variables with over 5000 observations, I have clustered and then found the optimal number of clusters using elbow method.

Now I'm not sure what to do because I'm left with 4 clusters which are still hard to interpret.

The aim of the analysis is to see if there are trends in the data.

Comment: Can you provide some more details here?  What are the data?  Trends in what?  Why do a cluster analysis in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think clustering helps you at what you aim to do. I think you should probably look into [association rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning) or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Hierarchical clustering is a nice tool to identify homogeneous subsets of responses (rows) with respect to the measured variables (your columns). If that is really what you're after, then following your clustering you will want to get a sense of the characteristics of each cluster. For variables that are categorical, you could calculate, for each cluster, the proportion of responses for each level of your categorical variables. For quantitative variables, the mean or median response for each variable in each cluster is usually useful. Parallel coordinate plots are also quite useful, especially when you have a large set of quantitative variables from which you derived your clusters. For example, here's a parallel coordinate plot showing attributes of the states, separated into four clusters. You can see that within each cluster states share a common pattern of responses across the variables. This is both a nice way to see what makes each cluster unique, and what makes clusters different.

[image: Parallel Coordinate Plot of State Attributes, By Cluster]

If your main interest is not in finding (and characterizing) homogeneous subsets (of rows) in your data, then you'll want to explore some different analyses. For instance, if you're interested in how your variables relate to each other, you might considering Multiple Correspondence Analysis (MCA), which, like its quantitative cousin Principle Components Analysis (PCA) will allow you to explore how your response variables relate to each other.

Comment: - Thanks for response

- Characterisation of each cluster is exactly what I meant. 

- I have never heard of Parallel coordinate plots but it looks useful

- Presumably each line represents each observations but if I have 1000 observations in one cluster then this graph surely become hard to interpret? Are there measures to counteract this?

Comment: You have exactly the right intuition there-with a large number of observations the plots get difficult to make sense of (unless there is significant homogeneity within each cluster). One thing I like to do in those situations is to make a parallel coordinate plot based on some aggregation of the within-cluster information. For instance, if in the example I posted I could find the mean response on each of those variables for each of the clusters, and then make a single plot where the separate lines are the clusters (not observations) and what is shown is teh mean response, not raw response

Answer (score 0):

Trend in what? The proportion of certain categories, or the values of the levels for the categorical variables?  I presume by 4 clusters, you mean 4 groups of observations, and not 4 groups of variables?

If your categorical values are like ranks (5 is better than 1, or vice versa) then calculate the averages of each rank variable within each of the 4 groups, then compare and plot averages of the ranks.  Otherwise, if the categorical values are truly nominal, like 1-chevy, 2-ford, 3-dodge truck, with no ordinality (directionality implying better or worse), then you have to calculate the proportions of each category within each categorical variable within each group.

Comment: Thanks for response!

When I say trends I mean patterns in the data or something like if certain variables are more useful than others

Yes when I say 4 clusters, I mean groups of observations.

It is a mixture or ordinal and nominal, mostly nominal. 
I will try to do what you have suggested. Are you aware of any other methods can be used to analyse the clusters?